# Chrome Extension add onClicked action to sub context menu items

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using this following script to add a context menu with two sub menu using Chrome Extension.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "context1",
    title: "Do it!",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "context2",
    title: "Do it too!",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
        var code = 'doit();';
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code });
    }
});
```

I want to know how to make each of them execute a different script using `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener`?

Here's my manifest file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "My Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
      "content_scripts": [ {
            "js": [ "jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "content.js"],
            "css": ["bootstrap.min.css"],
            "matches": [ "<Call_urls>" ]
         } ],
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["ctx.js"] //<- The file for script above.
    },

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Top google result: [Adding sub contextMenus in Google Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/47232155). Just don't specify `onclick`, instead check `info.menuItemId` in your single handler.

Comment: Yes, but with a separate onClicked listener. (I will update question for more clarification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to wOxxOm, I figured it out.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "context1",
    title: "First",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "context2",
    title: "Second",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
        if (info.menuItemId === "context1"){
            var code = 'alert("First Clicked");';
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code });
        }
        if (info.menuItemId === "context2"){
            var code = 'alert("Second Clicked");';
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code });
        }
    }
});
```

By using this above script. You will get separated alert for each item selected. Example: You will get alert `Second Clicked` if you selected the `Second` option.